# bootstrap shown.bs.modal not working so modal box not scroll to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

when I call one modal box over another , I tried this code for scroll to top to modal box. When i debug that code "shown.bs.modal" of bootstrap modal box event not working .

```
$(".modal-dialog .modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () { 
     $('.modal-dialog .modal .modal-body').scrollTop(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No element, no events:

```
console.log($('.modal-dialog .modal').is('div')) // => false
console.log($('.modal .modal-dialog').is('div')) // => true
```

Comment: sorry run perfectly on console but not working in actual code implementation.

Comment: @Himansu, the logs above are meant to show you the selector you're using is wrong. First one is what you are using, which selects nothing (it's not a div in your page). Second one is what you should be using.

Comment: my div structure is little bit different from this and if i run that code of console its return true but **shown.bs.modal**  is not working. When i debug that code it don't go inside that condition.

Comment: @Himanshu, so far you haven't even specified which version of Bootstrap you're using. Also, you're not supposed to alter Bootstrap markup (div structure). If you do, Bootstrap will no longer function properly. Last, but not least, if you do decide to use your custom markup, at least include it in the question. How do you expect anyone to know your markup, if you changed the default one? Please update your question with a [mcve].